# Bootstrap navbar dropbox does not show dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've read through a number of threads on stackoverflow about the `dropdown box` in the navigation bar but none of them have proved helpful for my problem.

I'm using bootstrap version 3 and I'm using the provided `navbar` example written on the official site:

```
  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar
```

I'm using the exact same code as on that site and im including the following javascript and css files:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/transition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/collapse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/footer.css" type="text/css">
```

I downloaded the different `js` and `css` files except from the `jquery` file.
I got this working before but not now even after a lot of troubleshooting, at that time the order of the script tags were wrong.

According to the bootstrap website the `jquery` plugin is necessary in addition to the collapse plugin being dependent on the transition plugin (so that is placed before the collapse plugin). Then the `dropdown js` and bootstrap in addition to the `css` files.

I cant figure out why this isn't working. The problem is that when i click on the `dropdown` box it doesn't show a menu at all, nothing happens. I've tried a lot of different configurations but nothing works.

I'm using this code:

```
     <html
     <head>
         <title>testing</title>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/transition.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/collapse.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/dropdown.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/footer.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've also tried to replaced all imports with the code erikrunia wrote in one of his replies, which is the same as on the example site as well.

This is how the page looks when its rendered by the browser:
[image]

After running a debugger on the site i get these warning/errors, but i also get a lot of these when visiting the bootstrap site itself so i dont know if they are related to the actual problem:

```
18:23:45.672 file:///Users/exceed/index.html
18:23:45.673 file:///Users/exceed/static/js/jquery.js
18:23:45.674 file:///Users/exceed/static/js/transition.js
18:23:45.674 file:///Users/exceed/static/js/collapse.js
18:23:45.675 file:///Users/exceed/static/js/dropdown.js
18:23:45.675 file:///Users/exceed/static/js/bootstrap.js
18:23:45.676 file:///Users/exceed/static/css/bootstrap.css
18:23:45.676 file:///Users/exceed/static/css/footer.css
18:23:45.643 Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:93
18:23:45.643 Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:195
18:23:45.643 Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:201
18:23:45.643 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-search-cancel-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:205
18:23:45.644 Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:306
18:23:45.644 Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:344
18:23:45.645 Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:1882
18:23:45.645 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:1888
18:23:45.645 Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:1913
18:23:45.645 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-outer-spin-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:1917
18:23:45.645 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:1965
18:23:45.645 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:1969
18:23:45.646 Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2262
18:23:45.646 Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2267
18:23:45.646 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2291
18:23:45.647 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:3555
18:23:45.650 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5459
18:23:45.650 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5460
18:23:45.650 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5476
18:23:45.650 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5477
18:23:45.650 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5487
18:23:45.650 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5488
18:23:45.650 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5498
18:23:45.650 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5499
18:23:45.650 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5509
18:23:45.650 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5510
18:23:45.650 Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5518
18:23:45.651 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5964
18:23:45.651 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5973
18:23:45.651 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6049
18:23:45.651 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6054
18:23:45.651 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6136
18:23:45.651 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6142
18:23:45.651 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6454
18:23:45.651 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6458
18:23:45.651 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6459
18:23:45.651 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6463
18:23:45.651 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6469
18:23:45.651 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6470
18:23:45.651 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6474
18:23:45.651 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6482
18:23:45.651 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'background-color'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:6541
18:23:45.658 TypeError: $(...).on is not a function collapse.js:160
18:23:45.659 TypeError: $(...).on is not a function dropdown.js:149
18:23:45.661 TypeError: $(...).on is not a function bootstrap.js:163
18:23:45.662 The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. index.html
```

Comment: I would assume bootstrap.js should be above transition.js.  Also try moving the two CSS imports above everything

Comment: I added bootstrap.js after jquery but still no luck. When im going to the example site it works when im clicking on the dropbox box so there is still something wrong

Comment: i would press f12 and see if you are getting any errors in your console.  Possible the path to your .js files is wrong and they are not loading at all.

Comment: I've used firebug and checked the access logs, they are found (status 200/304).. i always use cmd+r in chrome to make it query the server to check if the files are updated instead of just returning cache data directly from the browser

Comment: post your html that builds the navbar with the dropdown menu in it

Answer (score 0):

try using the CDN links provided by bootstrap instead of your imports to determine if it is your markup causing the issue or your JS imports.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

also, double check your navbar html markup is correct.  The dropdown menu is yet another UL embedded within the higher level ul/li that makes up the navbar.

Lastly, your `<html>` tag looks like `<html`, that will cause issues.  Also put in an appropriate doctype and meta viewport

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    ... rest of your code
```

Comment: Hmm, i removed all the imports and replaced them with your code but there is no change. I'll update the first post with a the code im using.

Comment: does your page itself render correctly aside from the dropdown not working?  can you include a screenshot of the navbar

Comment: Yes it is being rendered correctly. Ive attached a screenshot to the first post

Comment: your beginning <html> tag is missing the end bracket... was that a paste mistake or an actual issue?  See my updated comments in my answer about the html tag, the doctype, and the meta viewport.

Comment: that was not a pasting issue, ive added the end bracket as well as the doctype but still no change. Usually i add the doctype and have the proper indention but since it is just a test file to make it easier to isolate the problem i dropped it since i didnt though it would matter.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. It was a conflict between the dropdown.js file and another javascript file, probably bootstrap.js. When i removed dropdown.js the dropdown worked as it should. The documentation doesnt say that you need dropdown.js to make the navbar work but if you wanted a separate dropdown some place on your site then your navbar' dropdown would stop working because it seems like you cant have both bootstrap.js and dropdown.js imported at the same time which is a little wierd because you always need bootstrap.js anyway.. from what ive found, when importing both the dropdown is disabled without any warning message..some places it says that bootstrap already contain the functionality of dropdown but im not sure..this is an interesting read also [Bootstrap Dropdown not working - Dropdown doesn't toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333062/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-dropdown-doesnt-toggle)

In the bootstrap.js i now see that they implement functionality for what seems to be all the javascripts they have and i dont see in the documentation that they have done this, but not all files seems to be a conflict if you try to import it separately.